# Creating table dynamically by SQL in Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting error in this: prepared statement.

**Prepared Statement:**

```
PreparedStatement pStatement=connection.prepareStatement
("CREATE TABLE `details`.?(`ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`Score` VARCHAR(255) NULL);
INSERT INTO `testdetails`.? (`ID`) VALUES (?);");
pStatement.setString(1, "usrname");
pStatement.setString(2, "usrname");
pStatement.setString(3, "001");
pStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**Error details:**

```
Severe:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''usrname'(`ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`Score` VARCHAR(255) NULL);INSER' at line 1
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC parameters aren't usually usable for table and column names - they're only for *values*.

Unfortunately, I think this is one of those cases where you *will* need to be build the SQL dynamically. You will want to be *very* careful about which values you allow, of course.

Comment: yes, but how to make a new table and insert values into it dynamically?

Comment: @M.S.: As I said: build the SQL dynamically. Have you checked that the SQL works if you put the table names into the SQL manually?

Comment: @M.S. Besides the problem pointed out by Jon, you can't execute **two** statements at once.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because, you use `#setString`, and the string gets wrapped by `''`.

To fix this, you can use one of this snippets:

```
"CREATE TABLE `details`.#tableName#(`ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`Score` VARCHAR(255) NULL); INTO `testdetails`.#tableName# (`ID`) VALUES (?);".replaceAll("#tableName#", "usrname");
```

or

```
new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE `details`.").append("usrname").append("(`ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`Score` VARCHAR(255) NULL); INTO `testdetails`.").append("usrname").append("(`ID`) VALUES (?);").toString();
```

and pass resulted string into `#prepareStatement()` method.